# Angular $localize: How to use placeholders on attributes

Tags: angular, angular-localize

I'm using the runtime translation via loadTranslation() before the app initializes.
But this topic isn't described in a detailed way in the documentation.

I've found a solution for defining a placeholder value in the html like so:

```
<ng-container i18n="@@ID">{{ 'CUSTOM PLACEHOLDER VALUE' // i18n(ph="PH") }}</ng-container>
```

But this solution isn't described in the official documentation.

Furthermore I don't find any information how to set a placeholder in a attribute. How is it possible?
What would the example above look like for the e.g. placeholder attribute?

```
<input i18n-placeholder="@@ID" placeholder="<what to use the placeholder here?"/>
```

Comment: Try `i18n-placeholder="@@ID" placeholder='ID'`

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: How are the strings defined? Are you sure they are defined correctly?